# jquery animate rotate simultaneos

Tags: jquery, rotation, jquery-animate, simultaneous

I'm trying to animate an object and rotate simultaneosly. 
I'm using http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/ 
The rotate transition doesn't work.

```
$("#square")
.animate({top: "300px",left:"200px"},{duration:1800,queue: false})
.rotate({ angle:0,animateTo:-45,duration:1800 });
```

Another thing I would like to do is rotating with delay:

```
$("#square")
.animate({top: "300px",left:"200px"},{duration:1800,queue: false})
.delay(500)
.rotate({ angle:0,animateTo:-45,duration:1800 });
```

Comment: [link]http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/08/07/jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale.html have alook in this site

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your js files added properly. I just tested your code and it works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" id="image">
```

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/RwEme/5098/

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Because I want the image to move and rotate simultaneos

Answer (score 0):

Here this might help you with the continous rotation.

http://jsfiddle.net/xw89p/

```
 var rotation = function (){
   $("#image").rotate({
      angle:0, 
      animateTo:360, 
      callback: rotation,
      easing: function (x,t,b,c,d){        // t: current time, b: begInnIng value,
  c:   change     In value, d: duration
          return c*(t/d)+b;
      }
   });
}
 rotation();
```